# SharePoint 2013 lookups with more than 20 items as select or input?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, lookup-column, dropdown

So I was reading about doing some JavaScript to manipulate the default forms for our lists and came across this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/04/06/setting-sharepoint-drop-down-lists-w-jquery---20-items.aspx

This link basically amounted to if your dropdown has more than 20 elements, it will display funny because it is an input rather than a select. It's one line of code working with the select, but a good 15-20 lines to do the workaround to deal with the input tag.

I don't currently use the code for the more than 20 elements case, yet mine continues to work fine with 21 elements. I assume this is some difference between SharePoint 2013 (mine) and 2010 (used in the linked article).

My question is, has the need for this code been completely eradicated, or has the situation changed only slightly? Maybe instead of at 20 elements, the problem now doesn't occur until element 50, or maybe 100. How can I know that my system will scale without the extra code? I don't want to add superfluous code to my solution just because I don't know if there will be a problem.

Comment: Try adding a few hundred fake rows and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is how to add that many rows in a feasible amount of time. Also, it is possible that it just happens at, say, 500. Hopefully MS learned that that sucked and took it out. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation regarding any explanation regarding this in SharePoint 2013.

But practically my observation is that now(in SP2013) irrespective of number of items, every lookup field is rendered as a Drop-down/Select control.

Comment: Can you tell me the max number of items you have tried this with? 100? 500? 1000? If it were over 2000, that would be idea since lists degrade at that point anyway.

Comment: I tried with 450 items. To check this with more items in _`a feasible amount of time`_ you may find **Quick Edit** mode of list useful. Have some 1000's of random items created in an excel(just by dragging first cell value). Now, copy this column to your lookup list column in **Quick Edit** mode.

Comment: I had no idea you could mass copy spreadsheet cells into the in-browser quick edit. That is fantastic sir.